# What does the character , mean in bash?

Tags: linux, unix, bash

What does , mean in bash? For example what would the , in `accurev update -9 2>,update 1>&2` mean? (`accurev` is a version control software)

Sorry for the lame question, I just dunno how to google for special characters.

Comment: I bet it means someone's finger slipped while typing the > character.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It has no special meaning. The command redirects to a file called `,update`.

Answer (score 19):

A comma can be used in brace expansion, but there are no braces in the example you show.

This command would store its output in two files, one called "def" and the other called "abcdef":

```
echo hello | tee {,abc}def
```

or this one in "file1" and "file2":

```
echo hello | tee file{1,2}
```

Commas can be used to separate commands in an arithmetic operation in a `let` statement or the equivalent `(())` construction:

```
let a=1,b=2    # no spaces permitted
(( a = 1 , b = 2 ))
(( ++c, --d, e+=4 ))
```

You can use commas in a `for` statement to work with additional variables besides the primary index rather than putting the variable manipulation in the body of the `for`. It's probably bad programming practice to do this:

```
for ((i=1,j=4; i<4,j<7; i++,j+=2)); do echo $i $j; done
```

Commas can also be used in Bash 4 to change a string to lowercase (only a couple of variations are shown):

```
$ words="This is a TEST"
$ echo ${words,,}  # the whole string is lowercased
this is a test
$ echo ${words,}   # only the first character
this is a TEST
```

Comment: One file descriptor can only be redirected to _one_ file. `> {abc,def}` would fail with "Ambiguous redirect". (For several files, `tee` is usually used.)

Comment: @grawity: Of course you are correct. I've corrected my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Dennis is right in general, but your specific example runs `accurev update -9`, and puts the stderr output into a file called `,update` (with `,` as part of the filename), then puts stdout to the same place that stderr goes to (the file named `,update` in this case).

Answer (score -1):

there is a comma operator in bash that will run two commands but I don't believe it is used by your example check out the advanced bash scripting guide http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/ops.html

an example:

```
for ((a=1, b=1; a <= LIMIT ; a++, b++))
do  # The comma chains together operations.
  echo -n "$a-$b "
done
```

Comment: There isn't. Bash uses a semicolon for that `;`

Comment: @grawity: There is, but it's limited to arithmetic "commands" (see my answer).

Comment: if you look at the scripting guide you will see that there is a comma operator - see my updated answer